# Swift and Ionic framework

Tags: swift, ionic-framework

I want to move my app written on Swift in Ionic framework. What is the best way to achieve this?

Is there a workaround to write swift in Visual studio? What tools I need to set this project up.

p.s I work on PC and prefer visual studio

Comment: You need a mac for iOs development. The iOs SDK won't run on windows. You could use VirtualBox to run OsX virtually, but it's a slippery slope into mayhem and misery from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you need to re-write the whole logic/code of your application on a Javascript based framework  and use Ionic/AngularJS for the Frontend.

Comment: swift is for developing iOS App. Ionic is for developing Hybrid mobile Apps.

Comment: I know but I was thinking if there is a way to integrate the swift code into Ionic

Comment: Is it really necessary to move all logic to JavaScript? I thought ionic framework is for building interface and simplification using cordova, but what prevents from creating iOS project and overriding UIWebView methods where you can detect events and call swift code form there?